# Unable to use Windows XP Recovery Console when Administrator account has changed its name

Tags: windows-xp, recovery-console

I can't use Windows XP's Recovery Console, since I have changed the name of the Administrator account.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to modify the account using [Offline NT Password and Registry editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/). I know it is able to modify existing users, but I don't have the right test environment to check whether it can rename an account.